# Trying to add a node to the end of a LinkedList not working

Tags: c++, linked-list, nodes

I'm learning how to use LinkedLists and have run into a problem when trying to use them.

In my functions file I have:

```
LinkedList::Node* LinkedList::addNode(Node* head, string value)
{
    if (head == NULL)
    {
        return new Node(value);
    }
    if (head->next == NULL)
    {
        head->next = new Node(value);
        return head;
    }
    else
    {
        addNode(head->next, value);
    }
}
```

In my header file I have:

```
public:
LinkedList()
        {
            mHead = NULL;
        }

void addNode(string value)
        {
            addNode(mHead, value);
        }

private:
        struct Node
        {
            string value;
            Node* next;

            Node(string initValue, Node* initNext = NULL) :
                value(initValue), next(initNext)
            {}
        };

        Node* mHead;
        Node* addNode(Node* mHead, string value);
```

When trying to add to this list, nothing happens. I have two other functions, one to print out the size which is always 0 and to display the list to the console which is always blank. What do I need to change to my existing code to get my function to add a node to the list to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've corrected some issues in your code:

for example:

this line of code:

`LinkedList::Node* LinkedList::addNode(Node* head, string value)`

must be written like this:

`struct LinkedList::Node* LinkedList::addNode(struct Node* head, std::string value)`

here is a complete working example:

```
#include <iostream>  
#include <string>

class LinkedList {
    struct Node {
        std::string value;
        struct Node* next;

        Node(std::string initValue, Node* initNext = NULL) : value(initValue), next(initNext)
            {}
    };

    struct Node* mHead;
    struct Node* addNode(struct Node* head, std::string value);

    public:
        LinkedList()
        {
            mHead = NULL;
        }

        void addNode(std::string value)
        {
            addNode(mHead, value);
        }
};

struct LinkedList::Node* LinkedList::addNode(struct Node* head, std::string value)
{
    if (head == NULL)
    {
        if (mHead == NULL) {
            mHead = new Node(value);
            return mHead;
        }
        else{
            head = new Node(value);
            return head;
        }
    }
    if (head->next == NULL)
    {
        if (mHead ->next == NULL) {
            mHead->next = new struct Node(value);
            return mHead->next;
        }
        else{
            head->next = new struct Node(value);
            return head->next;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        addNode(head->next, value);
    }
}


int main()   
{  
    LinkedList myLinkedList;
    myLinkedList.addNode(std::string("value1"));
    myLinkedList.addNode(std::string("value2"));
    myLinkedList.addNode(std::string("value3"));
    myLinkedList.addNode(std::string("value4"));

    return 0;
}
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: I have corrected the last issue, now all my 4 values are added correctly at the end of the list.

Comment: Like my other comment said, the code works if it is a manually inputted variable but when I try to add it to my code that asks for a user input, it does not work.

Comment: I answered the question, as you asked it. you did not include other things in your question.

Comment: I included a pastebin with the rest of my code that this snippet is not working in.

Comment: your question is about adding at the end of the list, if there is another question. you have to update your code with this answer and ask another question. because right now you are asking me to debug another part of your work witch is not related to this question. I can look at it later.

Comment: Alright. It is just weird that it is not working. I'll try to figure it out but if you could look at it sometime later i'd appreciate it. I'll add another comment if I figure it out. Thanks.

Comment: I'm still not able to fix it. If you don't mind taking a lot at it i'd help a lot. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry I was busy. hope you have finished that work. good luck.

Comment: That's alright. I was able to fix it. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

`mHead` is always `NULL`. You should try changing it so that the first node created is assigned to `mHead`. Then `addNode` should work as expected.

I changed this

```
    void addNode(string value)
    {
        Node* node = addNode(mHead, value);
        if (mHead == NULL) mHead = node;
    }
```

and was able to insert elements into the list.

Comment: Where should try assignment it? I tried doing this in the public function of addNode and it still did not work.

Comment: if (head == NULL)
    {
        mHead = new Node(value);
        return mHead;
    }

Comment: @H.DJEMAI What is the other issue? I assigned the member variable now in the function but it still not assigning correctly.

Comment: @H.DJEMAI The other code does not affect this code though? I'm just confused why it is not updated the linklist. I am passing mHead as the parameter to the function so it should be using it.